# Work with DI in Asp .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

During the controller design I had the following question:
For example I have Controller that inject via constructor few services that work for more endpoints in that controller, further I want to add new functionality and add new endpoint to that controller as the result I need to add new Service injection to that controller, so system will instantiate of this services any time when user will use endpoints from that controller, even if user  does not use them.

What a best approach in this situation, should I inject IServiceScopeFactory insted of service via constructor (for those services that used rare in controller), and create service instances directly in endpoint method ?

Thank for any advice !

UPD: For injection I use native Asp.Net Core mechanism

Comment: you should inject it via the constructor. Try using Autofac DI which is a popular IoC mechanism for Web API 2.

Comment: maybe your controller hast too much responsibility and you should split it into multiple controllers. Otherwise I would not inject IServiceScopeFactory and leave it to the direct dependencies.